# Why does this output true and false?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've come across something a weird (at least it is to me), this is a simplified version of my problem

```
var $value = 123321;

var hex = /(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}/g;

var valid = (hex.test($value));
console.log(valid); // Outputs true.

valid = hex.test($value);
console.log(valid); // Outputs false.
```

Why does it give me 2 different outputs from running the same command twice?

Here's a JSFiddle to an example too, http://jsfiddle.net/wsu9xdv6/

Comment: Probably because of the `/g` (global) flag.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I didn't realise what the `g` flag did. Voted to close as dupe.